# How to programatically modify web browser content in design mode?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, browser, designmode

here's my dependency property declared :

```
public static void IsDesignModePropertyChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            WebBrowser browser = obj as WebBrowser;
            if (browser != null)
            {
                Boolean designMode = (Boolean)args.NewValue;
                if (designMode)
                {
                    browser.LoadCompleted += (s, e) =>
                    {
                        var htmlDoc = (s as WebBrowser).Document as IHTMLDocument2;
                        htmlDoc.body.setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");
                        htmlDoc.designMode = "On";
                    };
                }
                else
                {
                    browser.LoadCompleted += (s, e) =>
                    {
                        var htmlDoc = (s as WebBrowser).Document as IHTMLDocument2;
                        htmlDoc.body.setAttribute("contenteditable", "false");
                        htmlDoc.designMode = "Off";
                    };
                }
            }
        }
```

here's my web browser control :

```
<WebBrowser  viewmodel:BrowserBehavior.IsDesignMode="True"  x:Name="webBrowser1" viewmodel:BrowserBehavior.Html="{Binding SelectedNode.ContentData.FileName, Converter={StaticResource converter}, Mode=OneWay}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="612"/>
```

i would like to programatically modify the content of the web browser , and disable modification by keyboard ; i mean with a button that act on selection !

How is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

i found how to disable keyboard while `IsDesignMode ="true"`  :

```
<WebBrowser KeyDown="webBrowser1_KeyDown" ... />
```

in code behind :

```
private void webBrowser1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

Still looking for the answer of the second part of my question !